# Whether or Not to Use an Observable in my Angular 2 App

Tags: angular, socket.io, observable

I am trying to receive some tabular data via socket.io in my Angular 2 app. Initially I was using observables to handle this via http - and that was working as expected. However, in switching to sockets this is proving somewhat problematic. But now I'm wondering whether or not using an observable in this instance is really necessary. My assumption is that using observables is preferable when you have data that will be updating regularly. But in my case, I'm pulling in fairly static basic tabular data. Is using an observable in this instance necessary? Is it overkill?

This is what my code looked like when I was using http and wrapping it in an observable:

```
getByCategory() {
    return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map((response:Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this._errorsHandler);
}
_errorsHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

And, then, in my component, I was subscribing like this:

```
   this.contactService.getByCategory()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
```

This is what my service code looks like using sockets without using an observable. If something looks off, or could be written with an observable I'm open to hearing about that:

```
getByCategory() {
    console.log('getByCategory was just called on socket...');
    let socket = io.connect(this._url, this.args);
    socket.on('clients.getByCategory', function (data) {
        if (data === isNullOrUndefined) {
            console.log('No data to show!');
            return;
        }
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is overkill. An observable is really just a promise with some added features. What is your concern? The additional lib imports?

Comment: By default Http module in angular2 returns an observable. you can convert it to a promise by adding ".toPromise()" at the end of your method chain call... if you don't need an observable you could convert it to a promise

Comment: But do I really need either one? An observable or a promise?

Comment: Okay, I hear you. I'll use an observable then. Just have to figure out what that will look like.

Comment: I added code above to show how I was subscribing to the observable in the component.